# Input user into a list

Tags: python

I am trying to receive user input and then put it into a list. I have a working version, however, I feel as though it is redundant(the first block seems redundant, though if I take it away, it doesn't work). Any way this can be improved?
Thanks

```
def pastChoice():
     choice = raw_input("> ")
     prevMove = []
     prevMove.append(choice)

for i in prevMove:
     choice = raw_input("> ")
     prevMove.append(choice)
     print prevMove
```

pastChoice()

I am making a game and I want to show the user what choices they have already made.

Ex. Type 'history' if you would like to see previous choices

['a','a','c','b']

Comment: I cannot figure what you are trying to do with the code you gave. Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the length `prevMove` is always going to be 1, you know that, right?

Comment: I knew it would never end, but I didn't know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your intentions for this code, but this is roughly equivalent:

```
def pastChoice():
    prevMove = []

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")
        prevMove.append(choice)
        print prevMove
pastChoice()
```

the block:

```
 choice = raw_input("> ")
 prevMove = []
 prevMove.append(choice)
```

asks user for input and appends it to prevMove, so at loop start, the condition `i in prevMove` evaluates `i` to the first element in `prevMove`, then because in the second block you're appending new elements to `prevMove`, the iteration continues over those the newly appended elements and the loop never ends.

If you remove the first block, but keep the `for` loop, it won't work because there are no elements inside `prevMove` and therefore nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks, this really clarified things for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it this way? I don't know the real reason you are trying to do this, but to accept user input and add to a list this will do fine.

```
def main():
     prevMove = []
     choice = ''

     def getHistory():
          print prevMove

     while True:
          choice = raw_input("> ")
          if choice == '':
               break
          prevMove.append(choice)
          # do whatever you want with the input here

          # a call to history
          getHistory()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

---

EDIT:

Due to Questions edit, the code will now record the history of events and have a function to obtain them.

Comment: you can say `while choice:` instead of `while choice != '':`. That way, you can initialize choice as `choice = None`

Comment: @julio.alegria how so? That would have just skipped the while loop.

Comment: you're right about the loop condition (sorry about that), but still, the first tip is useful :)

Comment: it is, but you would have to change it to `while not choice` to get the behaviour you want.